# How do you use Data Analysis Expression (DAX) to Rank number based on Week number of Year?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking

I am looking to Dense Rank Amount of Clicks based on the week number of each year using Power BI.

The problem that I am running into is that the weeknumber is the same in the next year... and I cannot seem to get the DAX to sequence in a row correctly. Any ideas on what the DAX script would look like is appreciated.
[CODE]
             The output would look something like this:

```
         YearNumber WeekNumber NumberOfClicks RankNumClicks
           2020          1             362        8
           2020          1             325        9     
           2020          1             421        5
           2020          1             224        12
           2020          1             125        14
           2020          1             440        2
           2020          1             321        11
           2020          2             224        12
           2020          2             136        13
           2020          2             423        4
           2020          2             110        15
           2020          2             431        3
           2020          2             521        1
           2020          2             324        10
           2020          3             368        7
           2020          3             412        6
           2020          3... and so on.

      Here is what I think the DAX script should be like and what I have so
         far: (Please note that I used SalesAmount for number of clicks
         testing):
     Ranking = 
     VAR WeekNumberOfYear = ISFILTERED( DimDate[WeekNumberOfYear] )
     VAR FiscalYear = ISFILTERED( DimDate[CalendarYear] )

     RETURN
     IF( ISBLANK( 'FactInternetSales'[SaleAmounts] ), BLANK(),
     IF(FiscalYear, 
     RANKX( ALLSELECTED( DimDate[CalendarYear] ), 
       'FactInternetSales'[SaleAmounts], , DESC, Dense ),
     IF( NOT(  WeekNumberOfYear),
        RANKX( ALLSELECTED(DimDate[CalendarYear] ), 
            'FactInternetSales'[SaleAmounts], , DESC, Dense ),
         BLANK())) )
```

[image]

[/CODE]

Comment: Can you share your DAX code with us, so we can see what you did?

Comment: If the problem that you're having is related to multiple years, can you add some data to your expected results to show what should be happening in these weeks from different years?

Comment: Create a new column that concats year and week (201219), then rank on that, that will separate the weeks and year

Answer (score 0):

You can use newly introduced Hierarchy Slicer (go to Options and Settings, select Options, then Preview features under GLOBAL and check Hierarchy slicer).
[image]

Then, you can easily filter data based on specific Year/Week.

[image]

Hope this helps.